# Prioritizing Transactions in Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions

Let's say I need to perform two different kinds write operations on a datastore entity that might happen simultaneously, for example:

- The client that holds a write-lock on the entry updates the entry's content
- The client requests a refresh of the write-lock (updates the lock's expiration time-stamp)

As the content-update operation is only allowed if the client holds the current write-lock, I need to perform the lock-check and the content-write in a transaction (unless there is another way that I am missing?). Also, a lock-refresh must happen in a transaction because the client needs to first be confirmed as the current lock-holder.

The lock-refresh is a very quick operation.

The content-update operation can be quite complex. Think of it as the client sending the server a complicated update-script that the server executes on the content.

Given this, if there is a conflict between those two transactions (should they be executed simultaneously), I would much rather have the lock-refresh operation fail than the complex content-update.

Is there a way that I can "prioritize" the content-update transaction? I don't see anything in the docs and I would imagine that this is not a specific feature, but maybe there is some trick I can use?

For example, what happens if my content-update reads the entry, writes it back with a small modification (without committing the transaction), then performs the lengthy operation and finally writes the result and commits the transaction? Would the first write be applied immediately and cause a simultaneous lock-refresh transaction to fail? Or are all writes kept until the transaction is committed at the end?

Is there such a thing as keeping two transactions open? Or doing an intermediate commit in a transaction?

Clearly, I can just split my content-update into two transactions: The first one sets a "don't mess with this, please!"-flag and the second one (later) writes the changes and clears that flag.

But maybe there is some other trick to achieve this with fewer reads/writes/transactions?

Another thought I had was that there are 3 different "blocks" of data: The current lock-holder (LH), the lock expiration (EX), and the content that is being modified (CO). The lock-refresh operation needs to perform a read of LH and a write to EX in a transaction, while the content-update operation needs to perform a read of LH, a read of CO, and a write of CO in a transaction. Is there a way to break the data apart into three entities and somehow have the transactions span only the needed entities? Since LH is never modified by these two operations, this might help avoid the conflict in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datastore uses optimistic concurrency control, which means that a (datastore primitive) transaction waits until it is committed, then succeeds only if someone else hasn't committed first.  Typically, the app retries the failed transaction with fresh data.  There is no way to modify this first-wins behavior.

It might help to know that datastore transactions are strongly consistent, so a client can first commit a lock refresh with a synchronous datastore call, and when that call returns, the client knows for sure whether it obtained or refreshed the lock.  The client can then proceed with its update and lock clear.  The case you describe where a lock refresh and an update might occur concurrently from the same client sounds avoidable.

I'm assuming you need the lock mechanism to prevent writes from other clients while the lock owner performs multiple datastore primitive transactions.  If a client is actually only doing one update before it releases the lock and it can do so within seconds (well before the datastore RPC timeout), you might get by with just a primitive datastore transaction with optimistic concurrency control and retries.  But a lock might be a good idea for simple serialization of, say, edits to a record in a user interface, where a user hits an "edit" button in a UI and you want that to guarantee that the user has some time to prepare and submit changes without the record being changed by someone else.  (Whether that's the user experience you want is your decision. :) )